# PDO Prepare Statenent is returning only column names instead of values

Tags: php, select, pdo

I have written a function using PDO Prepare Statement to fetch columns from a table.

But its returning only the column names..

Could anyone help..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you can paste some code we could help. The typical PDO example is like the following:

```
<?php
function getFruit($conn) {
  $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
  foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Check your code and please, let us know more details about it.

Comment: Thanks.. The problem was I had changed column names mismatch with constructor arguments..