# PHP PDO MySQL array only returning column names

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am having an issue with my prepared SELECT result array not holding the actual column values. I know how to get data from an sql database using Java, however I am having issues with PHP PDO. I am connected to a remote AWS database that I know works. Here is the code:

```
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        //echo "Test";
```

Here I want to get all the column's data

```
        $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT 'id', 'short-des', 'full-des', 'image-urls', 'date-created' FROM projects");
        $sth->execute();
```

I have placed PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN. The result at the end of this post is a result of me leaving the fetchall() blank. When I insert any of the PDO::styles no values are returned. I have done other scenarios such as using var_dump along with the styles in the fetch statement which provide actual results, BUT no actual values that the columns contain.

```
        $row = $sth->fetchAll();

        echo "<br>" . $row[0] . "<br>";
        echo "<br>" . $row[1] . "<br>";

        $column1 = $row[0];
        $column2 = $row[1];

        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
            echo " " . $column1[$i];
            $var = $column1[$i];
            echo " = " . $var . " , ";

        }
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
            echo " " . $column2[$i];
            $var = $column2[$i];
            echo " = " . $var . " , ";
        }
```

This is the resulting text:

> 64-bitPDO is available
>
> Array
>
> Array
> id = id , short-des = short-des , full-des = full-des , image-urls = image-urls , date-created = date-created , id = id , short-des = short-des , full-des = full-des , image-urls = image-urls , date-created = date-created , Connected successfully

I'm guessing its some stupidly simple reason that it is not showing actual values. I am not familiar with the "fetch" concept since I'm coming from JDBC, however I have been spending the past few days trying to get it to work to no avail. I have looked at similar posts such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464600/pdo-prepare-statenent-is-returning-only-column-names-instead-of-values), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451126/pdo-fetchall-group-key-value-pairs-into-assoc-array), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796915/php-pdo-how-to-extract-mysql-data-to-multidimensional-array-without-number-keys). These seem to handle slightly different issues. Unfortunately I want to use a prepared statement instead of an actual query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is your single-quotes. Try this:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `short-des`, `full-des`, `image-urls`, `date-created` FROM projects");
```

Note: backticks `` ` `` are not the same as single-quotes `'`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not resolve the issue. I used single quotes because I saw somewhere that you can use them if your column names have key phrases in them.  The word 'fill' , and 'date' gets highlighted. $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, short-des, full-des, image-urls, date-created FROM projects");

Comment: @JosiahL. What does `var_dump($row);` output with this change? Actually, you use the backtick ` not '. Try it with the backtick now.

Comment: It fails to output anything. However this is what it outputs with the single quotes: array(2) { [0]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "id" [0]=> string(2) "id" ["short-des"]=> string(9) "short-des" [1]=> string(9) "short-des" ["full-des"]=> string(8) "full-des" [2]=> string(8) "full-des" ["image-urls"]=> string(10) "image-urls" [3]=> string(10) "image-urls" ["date-created"]=> string(12) "date-created" [4]=> string(12) "date-created" } [1]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "id" [0]=> string(2) "id" ["short-des"]=> string(9) "short-des" [1]=> string(9) "short-des" ["full-des"]=> string(8)

Comment: "full-des" [2]=> string(8) "full-des" ["image-urls"]=> string(10) "image-urls" [3]=> string(10) "image-urls" ["date-created"]=> string(12) "date-created" [4]=> string(12) "date-created" } }

Comment: Correction I just noticed that you said backticks. It displays data through the var_dump, and the route I have in the post.